# como defino aonde a minha animação de scroll(jquery) deve terminar como uma cordenada na pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Olá, gostaria de saber como defino uma localização aonde o efeito de scroll de site one page deve parar. 
O problema que enfrento é que ao dar um click em um dos links do meu menu de navegação no cabeçalho o scroll automático deslocasse até o conteúdo desejado mas corta partes do mesmo como o titulo do conteúdo, como defino aonde ele deve parar.

[image: O click no link do conteudo]

[image: O erro]

[image: O resultado desejado]

peço q observem com atenção por ser uma pergunta bem elaborada.

Comment: Isso acontece pq sua `navbar` está com `posítion:fixed` poste seu código completo que fica mais fácil de te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Na posição final que você passa pra função do animate, precisa subtrair a altura desse cabeçalho fixo. Ou seja, a coordenada vai ser a **posiçãoDoConteúdo - alturaDoHeader**.

Por exemplo:

```
$("html, body").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $(#sobre-nos).offset().top - $('#topo').outerHeight() 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: vou testar ja te falo se deu certo

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){        
                    event.preventDefault();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 1000);
                });
            });

Comment: este e o código

Comment: aonde devo fazer a alteração

Comment: ```{scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - 100},```

Troca o "100" pela altura do header.

Comment: cara muito obrigado você me ajudou demais eu ia ter que ficar revisando muita coisa pra achar isso nossa kkk fui lerdo de mais não observei uma coisa simples dessa